# parser.pm did not return a true value at

Tags: perl

Есть файл interface.pl, в нем записано:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use parser;

my $PROGNAME = "Spark";
my $PROGVERSION = 0.1;
```

при запуске выдает ошибку:

```
parser.pm did not return a true value at /Users/stolz/HolyLanguage/Spark/interface.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/stolz/HolyLanguage/Spark/interface.pl line 3.
```

файл parser.pm:

```
package Parser;
{
  my $val;
  1;
}
```

причем если вместо 1 я напишу `return 1`, мне дает ошибку:

```
Can't return outside a subroutine at /Users/stolz/HolyLanguage/Spark/parser.pm line 4.
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто вынесите `1;` за все фигурные скобки. Так нада. В книге с верблюдом всё написано.

Comment: я вынес, но в итоге теперь он ругается, мол `Can't locate parser.pm in @INC`

Comment: исправил эту проблему, прописав `BEGIN { unshift @INC, '/users/stolz/spark'; }`, а можно как-то обойтись без этой записи?

Comment: `use lib '/users/stolz/spark';` умно добавляет каталог в `@INC`

Answer (score 0):

По сути, вам фигурные скобки и не нужны. Можно их просто убрать.